# How to get string in web browser in windows phone 8?

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, windows-phone-8.1

I have a file html, and i want to get string from this file html. I use web browser for read html, but i don't know how to get string in web browser. Can't you help me. Thank all!

```
WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
web.Source = new Uri("Assets/text.html", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Comment: which string you want? show the code where string is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebBrouser = new WebBrowser();
WebBrouser.Navigate(new Uri("Assets/text.html", UriKind.Relative);
```

I am assumed that your html file content is in proper format.